# Spring Dynamic Module - Parse Exception while deploying the osgi bundle to IBM Liberty

Tags: spring, dynamic, osgi, blueprint-osgi, eclipse-gemini

I am getting the below parse exception while deploying the SPRING DM OSGI bundle into the IBM Liberty.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 2 in XML document from URL
>   [bundleentry://240.fwk843512726/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd; lineNumber:
>   2; columnNumber: 35; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are
>   not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and
>   'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Probably has to do with some type of invalid character in your `applicationContext.xml`. May be use a XML [tool ](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/) to validate it externally.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "legacy" Spring DM, then the "blueprint" namespace is not the one you should use. This xsd is not packaged in the bundles of your container : SpringDM try to download it from the network, and some proxy/web server sends an HTTP redirect (301), which is not a valid xsd document..

With SpringDM, you should use only Spring namespaces.

However, SpringDM is obsolete now, and should not be used.. You can use Blueprint, or better Declaratives Services.

There are two implementations of Blueprint you can use : Aries-Blueprint, or Gemini Blueprint (which supports Spring 4.3, Blueprint and is more or less compatible with SpringDM)

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply!  as advised, i have changed to Gemini Blueprint to replace Spring DM, but at the end i am still getting the same error.  Any reference or example , which can help me to come out of this problem?

Comment: gemini-blueprint gives us the same error, tried all versions.
I think it is because http_www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd was  recently moved to https_osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd.
But gemini-blueprint is not handling this correctly.